# Results from API can be logged to the console but cannot be rendered on the UI. Attempting to map results in Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get the information from a free api to display on my page. I am building a crypto app with React and I can use console.log(response.data) to see the array, but the second I try to change the console.log to setCoinList(response.data.coins) I get this error:

***Uncaught TypeError: coinList.map is not a function***

I am using axios and I don't think the issue is with the get, I can return the info to the console and view it, and I am starting with a blank array, so I don't know what is wrong here.

Here is the code in question:

```
function App() {

  const [coinList, setCoinList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://openapiv1.coinstats.app/coins",
      params: { limit: "20" },
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": MYAPIKEYHERE,
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then((response) => {
        setCoinList(response.data.coins);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (

<div className="container mx-auto mt-8">
        {coinList.map((coin) => {
          return (
            <Coin
              key={coin.rank}
              name={coin.name}
              icon={coin.icon}
              symbol={coin.symbol}
              volume={coin.volume}
              price={coin.price}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The syntax appears correct because my editor isn't throwing an error over the syntax, but for whatever reason the values won't load. The Coin component also isn't throwing any errors. The values for the API appear correct Is it possible map doesn't have anything to map because the data isn't loaded yet? How do I ensure I get this data first? Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I tried to change the code to this:

```
<div className="container mx-auto mt-8">
        {coinList && coinList.map((coin) => {
          return (
            <Coin
              key={coin.rank}
              name={coin.name}
              icon={coin.icon}
              symbol={coin.symbol}
              volume={coin.volume}
              price={coin.price}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

I'm not getting any errors, but nothing is being displayed on the UI

EDIT:

The console is showing the array twice -

[image]

Comment: Is it possible response.data.coins contains something different than you think?

Comment: console logging it shows me the information I am expecting. Whenever I try to return the info is when I was getting the errors. After add the coinList && coinList.map part I am not longer getting the error but nothing is appearing. I am also getting two arrays in my console for some reason like it is running twice.

Comment: I'm an idiot... setCoinList(response.data.coins) should be setCoinList(response.data.result) .. Thank you Amy, and have a wonderful night.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setCoinList(response.data.coins)`, use  `setCoinList(response.data.result)` in your useEffect callback. There is no `coins` key in the `response.data` object.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://openapiv1.coinstats.app/coins",
      params: { limit: "20" },
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": MYAPIKEYHERE,
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then((response) => {
        setCoinList(response.data.result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```